# Array into MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a JSON string that contains two objects, peoples names and their associated phone numbers, which appears as follows (the Name and Phone will ALWAYS be the same length):

```
{"Name":["Name One","Name Two","Name Three"],"Phone":["123465789","3216546564","15641654654"]}
```

I am trying to insert this into a MySQL database via PHP but am struggling a bit how to insert both values in the same loop.

PHP code is as follows so far:

```
<?php

$dbuser = "";
$dbpassword = "";
$database = "";

$result;
$resultSuccess;

$user = $_POST['user'];
$proc_name = $_POST['proc_name'];
$person_name_contacts = $_POST['person_name_contacts'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $dbuser, $dbpassword, $database);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
$result = 'Database Connection Failed';
}else{

$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user);
$proc_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$proc_name);
$person_name_contacts = 
mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$person_name_contacts);

$person_name_contacts=json_decode($person_name_contacts);

foreach($person_name_contacts as $value) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO evac_people (user, evac_procedure, person_name,  
person_contact)
        VALUES     ('".$user."','".$proc_name."','".$person_names."','".$person_contacts."')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if($mysqli->error === ""){
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }
}

}
?>
```

Comment: I try to avoid executing sql queries inside loops. Build all the VALUES inside the loop, and then execute the query, once, afterwards. And see about sql injection!!

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injection attacks. You apparently have ultimate trust into the data source you are using...

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly is it that you ask from us?

Comment: How can I get the 123465789 and Name One into the SQL at the same position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I did not understand this, it should go:

```
 foreach ($person_name_contacts['Name'] as $k =>$value) {
    $person_name = $value;
    $person_contact = $person_name_contacts['Phone'][$k];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO evac_people (user, evac_procedure, person_name,  person_contact)
            VALUES     ('" . $user . "','" . $proc_name . "','" . $person_name . "','" . $person_contact . "')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($mysqli->error === "") {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

A better solution in agreement with [@Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO evac_people (user, evac_procedure, person_name,  person_contact) VALUES ";
$sqlValue = array();
foreach ($person_name_contacts['Name'] as $k =>$value) {
    $person_names = $value;
    $person_contacts = $person_name_contacts['Phone'][$k];
    $sqlValue[] = "('" . $user . "','" . $proc_name . "','" . $person_names . "','" . $person_contacts . "')";
}
if (!empty($sqlValue)) {
    $sql = $sql . implode(',', $sqlValue);
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($mysqli->error === "") {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. Let me know if it works.

```
    $json = '{"Name":["Name One","Name Two","Name Three"],"Phone":["123465789","3216546564","15641654654"]}';

    $result = json_decode ($json);

    $array = array();

    foreach ($result->Name as $k =>$value)
    {
        $name = $value;
        $contact = $result->Phone[$k];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO evac_people (user, evac_procedure, person_name,  person_contact)
             VALUES     ('".$user."','".$proc_name."','".$name."','". $contact . "')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($mysqli->error === "") {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }

    }
```